# Steps to get PhpStorm 5.0.2 + XDebug working in Windows

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I am looking for the simplest steps possible to get PhpStorm 5.0.2 to debug a simple PHP page.  I tried a dozen different sets of instructions I found on the web, including those from JetBrains and I couldn't get it to work.

Environment:

IIS Express 8 + PHP 5.4 running on Windows 8.  PhpStorm 5.0.2 just installed.  This works, PHP page is at `http://localhost:13602/sphp.php` and `https://localhost:44307/sphp.php` (secure version) and shows up as expected with the code looking like this:

```
<?
php echo ("Hello!")
?>
```

Steps:

I reset all other steps I took, so PhpStorm is absolutely back to out of the box settings.  Then I performed the following two steps:

1. In PhpStorm, under "File" > "Settings" > "PHP". I set the "PHP language level" to "5.4" and the "Interpreter" to the right path for my "PHP 5.4" installation.
2. I followed instructions from "xdebug.org" and added the XDebug extension to my environment, that means I downloaded and added "php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll" to the "ext" folder under my "PHP 5.4" installation folder, unblocked it (since it was downloaded from the internet), and added the following line to the end of "php.ini" as suggested by the instructions, under no section whatsoever:

   zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9-nts.dll"

So far... not working too well...

Comment: Check these manuals (#4 and #6) -- it's enough to make it work: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Documentation . I also suggest checking the output of `phpinfo();` to verify that xdebug is actually installed.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Xdebug+installation+guide had the information I needed to verify that I was even loading Xdebug and that helped me find out that I was not, I was editing the wrong php.ini.  Aaargh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information at confluence.jetbrains.net/display/WI/Xdebug+installation+guide had pretty much all the answers.